# Overloading a package funcion to detect no arguments have been used

Tags: raku, rakudo

I am trying to overload a function to detect no arguments have been passed:

```
package Documentable::CLI {

        sub RUN-MAIN(|c) is export {
            my %*SUB-MAIN-OPTS = :named-anywhere;
            CORE::<&RUN-MAIN>(|c)
        }

        our proto MAIN(|) is export { * }

        multi MAIN (
            Bool :V(:$version)
        ) {}

        multi MAIN () {
            say 'Execute "documentable --help" for more information'
        }

    }

    # no output
    Documentable::CLI::MAIN();
```

If you try to use `multi main (*@args) {}` it will not work either. BUT if you delete the first `multi MAIN` definition everything will work smoothly. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Are you sure you can add a proto for MAIN? Also, why do you want to do that? If it's printing an usage you're looking for, there are other ways.

Comment: What leads you to ask if one can add a proto MAIN? It would seem intuitive that it would work in a matter consistent with other routines.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The signature `:(Bool :V(:$version))` accepts no argument, because the argument `version` is optional, and it is more specific than the signature `:()`. You could make the argument `version` mandatory

```
multi MAIN (
    Bool :V( :$version )!
) {}
```